# How to run single Maven test case in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, maven

In Jenkins my job is of type "Build a maven2/3 project" and project name is "SeleniumProject" and project source is "SVN" contains around 40 test cases. When I build this, it runs all test cases and 3 of them fail. How can I execute an individual test in this project? These test cases are coming under module "automation". Where do I need to configure build to run only one test case?

Answer (score 3):

Use `-Dtest=<test class name>` or `-Dtest=<test class name>#<test method name>` as specified at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

ps: use StackOverflow for programming questions - they'll get answered sooner

Comment: It is not working in jenkins, In project level all test cases are running, in module level no test cases are running

Comment: Just created a test jenkins job for a multimodule project.
Added `-DfailNoTests=false -Dtest=<test class name>` to its 'Goals and options' in a 'Build' section (i.e. my 'Goals and options' param looks like `-DfailNoTests=false -Dtest=<test class name> install`).
As a result the whole project was built, only the specified test class was executed.